# Microsoft CRM 3.0 User Doesn't Have Option to Print Contact Info

Tags: permissions, dynamics-crm

I've been tasked with giving people access to a MS CRM 3.0 install.  I start out with the minimal "Read Only" role by default.  However, a user just called to notify me that when opening a contact, the File menu only has "Properties" and "Close" -- no option to print.

Does anyone know what roles/permissions are required for the print option to become available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a "Print" privilege under the "Miscellaneous Privileges" section of the "Business Management" tab.